# Install custom theme on SharePoint 2019 server

Tags: sharepoint, themes

I have created a custom theme using Microsoft's theme generator tool, I have copied the theme that it has generated. But now all the documentations of installing the theme are related to SP Online, I want to know how can we install it on SP 2019 on prem ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the theme changes and applications of SharePoint 2019 are still consistent with those of SharePoint 2013. For details, please refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/themes-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-composed-looks-to-brand-sharepoint-sites